# How to convert to byte hungarian characters using DOS-extended ASCII character set

Tags: c#, encoding, ascii, special-characters

I have a task to export Hungarian text data using DOS-extended ASCII character set. Unfortunately I have very limited experience in byte-level programming, so the issue may be my misunderstanding of something, but [Encoding 852](https://hu.wikipedia.org/wiki/852-es_k%C3%B3dlap) seem to have the characters I need. The example word below contains all special characters related to Hungarian language:

> Árvíztűrő Tükörfúrógép

The most special characters are "ő" and "ű" these are as far as I know not present in most other sets. I am using the code below in order to achieve my goal:

```
public byte[] GenerateToken(char TokenName, List<string> tokenValues) {
    var tokenLen = 4; // Header
    Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(850);
    foreach (var token in tokenValues) {
      tokenLen += encoding.GetByteCount(token) + 1;
    }
    tokenLen += 2; // cr lf
    byte[] tokenData = new byte[tokenLen];
    int index = 0;
    var len = (short)tokenLen;
    // Header
    tokenData[index++] = (byte)len;
    tokenData[index++] = (byte)(len >> 8);
    tokenData[index++] = (byte)TokenName;
    tokenData[index++] = 0;
    // Token Data
    foreach (var token in tokenValues) {
      var buf = encoding.GetBytes(token);
      buf.CopyTo(tokenData, index);
      index += buf.Count();
      tokenData[index++] = 0;
    }
    // End marker
    tokenData[index++] = (byte)'\r';
    tokenData[index] = (byte)'\n';
    return tokenData; }
```

Here is an example for the desired output:

[image: Example1]

With the information above I have managed to send the data to the destination, but when I check it the example *"Árvíztűrő Tükörfúrógép"* becames *"┴rvφzturo Tⁿk÷rf·r≤gΘp2"* which is of course, not my intention. The destination is capable of handling the characters I need (tested) so the issue must be on my side:

[image: Example2]

This picture shows a debugging phase just before I send my data to the destination, I am using [System.Text.Encoding.Default.Getstring()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getstring?view=net-6.0) to watch the byte data sent, and it seems to be incorrect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Given the current information, it's difficult to help you. Is the source or the target using "DOS-extended ASCII character set"? And you have to agree on a specific code page with whatever party you are exchanging data. So should codepage 852 be used? And for several variables in your code, the declaration is missing. So we can't tell what type they are.

Comment: Additionally, the way you inspect the data in the Watch window is helpful in anyway. I can't see the full expression, but you seem to pass it a binary data structure and convert it into a string using the default encoding. This cannot possibly create a sensible result.

Comment: @Codo thank you for your comments, I've updated the code; I simply missed the first line of the function, which is indeed essential, sorry for the mistake. The source is a list of string.

Comment: And what about all the other questions?

Comment: The Watch window watches the exact thing I am sending to the destination using the function in my question. The list is good, the result is wrong. The list is made with strings using no specified encoding, what is the "default" encoding when I declare a string in C#?

Comment: @Codo Codepage 852 is a DOS-extended ASCII character set containing hungarian characters, so yes, my intention is to use 852.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239444/discussion-between-viktor-and-codo).

Comment: It looks like your code is working just fine, but the expression in the Watch window is nonsense. Or do you have any other indication that your code is not working?

Comment: @Codo Strange. The destination is a bridge app sending the data to an SQL database using Latin1_General_CI_AS collation; the word "Árvíztűrő Tükörfúrógép" becames "┴rvφzturo Tⁿk÷rf·r≤gΘp2". Is 852 an incorrect encoding in this case?

Comment: If the bridge app is known to work, even for special Hungarian letters, then we have insufficient information about the input format it expects. If the bridge app is new and likely part of the problem, then we are missing any information about it. In either case, I don't see how any StackOverflow user can help you given the current information.

Comment: A flagrant [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: `"Árvíztűrő Tükörfúrógép".encode('cp1250').decode('cp852')` returns `'┴rvÝztűr§ TŘk÷rf˙rˇgÚp'` (I prefer Python to demonstrate _mojibake_ instead of clumsy `.NET` counterpart).

Comment: Or in `.NET` (_PowerShell_ syntax): `[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding( 437).GetString( [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding( 1252).GetBytes( [char[]]"Árvíztűrő Tükörfúrógép"))` returns your mojibake `┴rvφzturo Tⁿk÷rf·r≤gΘp`…

Comment: Switch to [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/)…